# MSVC error: none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencl

I am trying to compile jugCLer from [ocltoys](https://github.com/ignatenkobrain/ocltoys/tree/master/jugCLer), and defeated all errors except one. What to do with it?

Code:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Compile kernel
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

const std::string &kernelFileName = commandLineOpts["kernel"].as<std::string>();
OCLTOY_LOG("Compile OpenCL kernel: " << kernelFileName);

// Read the kernel
const std::string kernelSource = ReadSources(kernelFileName, "jugCLer");

// Create the kernel program
cl::Device &oclDevice = selectedDevices[0];
cl::Context &oclContext = deviceContexts[0];
cl::Program program = cl::Program(oclContext, kernelSource);
```

Log:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: jugCLer, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  jugCLer.cpp
1>..\..\ocltoys-unocltoys\jugCLer\jugCLer.cpp(398): error C2665: 'cl::Program::Program' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>          C:\ATI Stream SDK\ATI Stream SDK v2 Developer\include\CL/cl.hpp(2392): could be 'cl::Program::Program(const cl::Context &,const cl::Program::Sources &,cl_int *)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(cl::Context, const std::string)'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please do not tag C++ questions with C.

Comment: Which version of OpenCL are you building with? It's probably more recent than the Juggler code (which is six years old).

Comment: Ati Stream SDK 2.2, I not know version in this sdk. CL headers in this sdk were created in 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was fixed only by changing the code, nothing else helped.

Before:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Compile kernel
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

const std::string &kernelFileName = commandLineOpts["kernel"].as<std::string>();
OCLTOY_LOG("Compile OpenCL kernel: " << kernelFileName);

// Read the kernel
const std::string kernelSource = ReadSources(kernelFileName, "jugCLer");

// Create the kernel program
cl::Device &oclDevice = selectedDevices[0];
cl::Context &oclContext = deviceContexts[0];
cl::Program program = cl::Program(oclContext, kernelSource);
```

After:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Compile kernel
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

const std::string &kernelFileName = commandLineOpts["kernel"].as<std::string>();
OCLTOY_LOG("Compile OpenCL kernel: " << kernelFileName);

// Read the kernel
const std::string kernelSource = ReadSources(kernelFileName, "jugCLer");
cl::Program::Sources source(1, std::make_pair(kernelSource.c_str(), kernelSource.length()));
// Create the kernel program
cl::Device &oclDevice = selectedDevices[0];
cl::Context &oclContext = deviceContexts[0];
cl::Program program = cl::Program(oclContext, source);
```

Answer (score 0):

In [cl.hpp](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/api/2.1/cl.hpp), there are four constructors for cl::Program, one of which is as follows.

```
Program(const Context& context, const STRING_CLASS& source, bool build = false, cl_int* err = NULL)
```

STRING_CLASS is a typedef of cl::string which accepts a c-style string in the constructor. You could try.

```
cl::Program program = cl::Program(oclContext, kernelSource.c_str());
```

In the newer header [cl2.hpp](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/cl2_8hpp_source.html), string is another name for std::string (`using string = std::string`). You should probably use this more up to date header.

Comment: Same error

`2>..\..\ocltoys-unocltoys-fix\jugCLer\jugCLer.cpp(398): error C2665: 'cl::Program::Program' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types
2>          C:\ATI Stream SDK\ATI Stream SDK v2 Developer\include\CL/cl.hpp(2392): could be 'cl::Program::Program(const cl::Context &,const cl::Program::Sources &,cl_int *)'
2>          while trying to match the argument list '(cl::Context, const char *)'
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: New code: `const std::string &kernelFileName = commandLineOpts["kernel"].as<std::string>();
  OCLTOY_LOG("Compile OpenCL kernel: " << kernelFileName);

  // Read the kernel
  const std::string kernelSource = ReadSources(kernelFileName, "jugCLer");

  // Create the kernel program
  cl::Device &oclDevice = selectedDevices[0];
  cl::Context &oclContext = deviceContexts[0];
  cl::Program program = cl::Program(oclContext, kernelSource.c_str());`

Comment: And cl2.hpp shows error: `error :  Visual studio 2013 or another C++11-supporting compiler`. I can't update visual studio and not needed.

Comment: And this error when I use 2012-2013 headers `error C2664: 'clEnqueueNativeKernel' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'void (__stdcall *)(void *)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void *)'
1>          This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or function-style cast`

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!vyRRBQzT!LoiAmfwBn_YwfkXpKcPbJsVw_P6BVZXAwq9-DHRI88c Only header that worked for 5/6 targets (except for jugCLer) is 2010. Other ends with errors on 5/6 or 6/6.